# Laravel - Select Destination Count for the two months from Current Date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Larave-5.8 for a Web Application. I already have the code below.

```
$destination = Trip::select('destination')
   ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
   ->groupBy('destination')
   ->orderByDesc('count')
   ->limit(5)
   ->get();
```

How do I modify the code to get Trip Destination Count for the Past two months from the current date?

Comment: ->where('created_at', '>', (new \Carbon\Carbon)->submonths(2) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your query already works, you can get that using `whereDate` method.. like this:

```
$destination = Trip::select('destination')
   ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS count')
   ->groupBy('destination')
   ->orderByDesc('count')
   ->whereDate('created_at', '>', now()->subMonths(2))
   ->limit(5)
   ->get();
```

Or if you want 2 months in the future, instead of `subMonths` use `addMonths(2)`.